# Linked List from Linked List

Tags: c, linked-list

I am trying to create an (ordered) linked list of (ordered) linked lists. The list-of-list links are carried by the first nodes of its member lists. I am trying to achieve this via the following code, but my program crashes when I try displaying the second list. First list displays perfectly.

Here's a schematic of the data structure I am trying to construct:
[image]

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>

struct node{
   int number;
   struct node*next;
   struct node*lsnext;
};

typedef struct node Node;
Node* insertValue(Node * list, int value);
void display(Node*);
Node* insertArr(Node * list, int value);
Node* addNodeBottom(int val, Node *start);

int main()
{

Node *globalList = NULL, *lists,*start,*save;
int nbrOfLists, listNo, nbrOfVal, valNo, val;

start=NULL;

printf("\n Enter the number of lists:");
scanf("%d", &nbrOfLists);

if(nbrOfLists < 0)
    return -1;

for(listNo = 0; listNo < nbrOfLists; listNo++)
{
    printf("\n\n Enter the number of inputs to the list %d: \n ",listNo+1);
    scanf("%d", &nbrOfVal);
    lists = NULL;

    for(valNo = 0; valNo < nbrOfVal; valNo++)
    {
        printf("Enter node value %d:", valNo+1);
        scanf("%d", &val);
        // Here we insert the value in both lists
        lists= insertValue(lists, val);
        globalList = insertValue(globalList, val);
    }

    start=addNodeBottom(val,lists);
    if(listNo==0){
        save=start;
    }
    printf("\n  The list %d is: ",listNo+1);
    display(lists);

}
   printf("\n\n The final list is: ");
   display(globalList);
   printf("The first list is");
   display(save);
   printf("The second list is");
   display(save->lsnext);  //crashes here
   return 0;
}

Node* insertValue(Node * list, int value)  //to insert node at the end
{
   Node *newNode, *m;
   newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
   newNode->number=value;

  if(list == NULL)
  {
     newNode->next=NULL;
     return newNode;
   }

  if(value < list->number)
  {
      newNode->next = list;
      return newNode;
  }

 m = list;
 while(m->next)
 {
     if(value < m->next->number)
        break;
     m = m->next;
 }
 newNode->next = m->next;
 m->next = newNode;
 return list;
 }

Node* addNodeBottom(int val, Node *start)
{
    Node*rear;
    Node* node1=(Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));

    node1->number=val;
    node1->lsnext=NULL;

    if(start==NULL){
        start=rear=node1;
    }
    else{
        rear->lsnext=node1;
        rear=node1;
    }
  return start;
 }

 void display(Node*nodex){

    while(nodex)
    {
        printf("%d ->",nodex->number);
        nodex=nodex->next;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Could you please specify "crashes" and provide the exception if there is any?

Answer (score 1):

This code invokes undefined behaviour. In particular, your function `addNodeBottom` is buggy: If invoked with `start` not NULL, it modifies the member `rear->lsnext`, but `rear` is uninitialised at that point. I assume, you intended to modify `start` instead. Here, you return `start` unmodified, so it's member `lsnext` is not set to anything useful, which probably eventually leads to a segmentation fault. However, in principle already the offending function call to `addNodeBottom` could lead to unexpected program termination.